# How to go onto next available cell in excel using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv

So i have the code :

```
user1 = input("What is player 1's first name?")
user2 = input("What is player 2's first name?")
import csv

with open('scores.csv', 'r+', newline='') as csvfile:
  fieldnames = ['username', 'score']

  writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
  writer.writerow({'username': user1, 'score': '1'})
  writer.writerow({'username': user2, 'score': '2'})
  row = next()

  csvfile.close
```

for a school project involving reading and writing csv files with excel. The output is:

```
Username,score
Joe,1
Blogs,2
```

But when the code is ran again with different usernames it overwrites the first set of usernames.

All i need to know is how to go to the next available set of cells to input the new users

-Thank you in advance

Comment: you don't need `csvfile.close` delete that line.

Comment: use `'a+'` not `'r+'` to append to the file. Also, you could read in all the data then just add the new rows to the end, but that is less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

@Eli Harold is correct that you don't need `csvfile.close`. When you use the `with open()` syntax, python automatically closes the file when the block is done (when you go back  to un-indented code).

They are also correct that if you wanted to simply append to the file you should use "a+". However, you also have to keep in mind that the first time you write to the file you want to include a header and after that you don't. It would be easier if you could have all your data and write it all in one go rather than running the same code again to write more data.

However, assuming you want to go through with this write multiple times strategy, here's some code.

I did this in two ways

```
# It's good practice to put the import statements at the top
import csv
# This is what will allow you to check whether or not the scores.csv file exists yet
from os.path import exists

user1 = input("What is player 1's first name?")
user2 = input("What is player 2's first name?")

fieldnames = ['username', 'score']

# ------ Solution 1 -------
if exists("scores.csv"):
    # You don't need `newline=''`
    with open('scores.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow({'username': user1, 'score': '1'})
        writer.writerow({'username': user2, 'score': '2'})
else:
    # Note over here we are using 'w' because no file exists yet and
    # we are writing a header.
    with open('scores.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'username': user1, 'score': '1'})
        writer.writerow({'username': user2, 'score': '2'})

# ------ Solution 2 --------
# This solution is cleaner.
write_header = not exists("scores.csv")
with open('scores.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    if write_header:
        writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'username': user1, 'score': '1'})
    writer.writerow({'username': user2, 'score': '2'})
```

You don't need `newline=''`. You can check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for more details but without it csv.reader will still work.

Comment: Dude thanks, This helped me alot. Again thank you :)

Comment: You should hit the check next to the up down arrows on my post to mark that my post answered your question.

Comment: i cant due to low rep :(